# Lazy Load images initial images not showing

Tags: javascript, image, smarty

My website is built using Smarty template and I am using Lazy Load to show 15 images per page, the issue I am having is the first images (which are in viewport) are not initially showing, they only show up when I begin to scroll, any thoughts how I can get the initial images in sight to show straight away. This is the code I have to Lazy Load the images

```
<script id="rendered-js">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",        
function () {
var lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll("img.listing-photos");
var lazyloadThrottleTimeout;
function lazyload() {
if (lazyloadThrottleTimeout) {
  clearTimeout(lazyloadThrottleTimeout);
}
lazyloadThrottleTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
  lazyloadImages.forEach(function (img) {
    if (img.offsetTop < window.innerHeight + scrollTop) {
      img.src = img.dataset.src;
      img.classList.remove('lazy');
    }
  });
  if (lazyloadImages.length == 0) {
    document.removeEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
    window.removeEventListener("resize", lazyload);
    window.removeEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
  }
}, 2);
}
document.addEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
window.addEventListener("resize", lazyload);
window.addEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
}); 
</script>
```

and this is the output HTML code

```
{foreach from=$results item="entry"}
<div class="showlistings1">
<center>{if $entry.image != ""}<img class="listing-photos" 
data-src="/photos/{$entry.image|escape:"url"}" alt="{$entry.title}"/>
{else}<img class="listing-photos" data-src="/images/nophoto.gif" 
alt="{$entry.title}"/>{/if} <p><a href="/{$entry.link}" 
class="full-details">View Full Details</p></a></center>
</div>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Why do you trigger the "lazyload" of the images on `scroll`, `resize` and `orientationChange` and not directly on `DOMContentLoaded`?

Comment: unsure how to implement it into the code I have, any help gratefully appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a callback that runs at DOMContentLoaded, which means the DOM is available for analysis. Just call your `lazyload` function once before setting up your event listeners.

```
<script id="rendered-js">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",        
function () {
var lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll("img.listing-photos");
var lazyloadThrottleTimeout;
function lazyload() {
if (lazyloadThrottleTimeout) {
  clearTimeout(lazyloadThrottleTimeout);
}
lazyloadThrottleTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
  lazyloadImages.forEach(function (img) {
    if (img.offsetTop < window.innerHeight + scrollTop) {
      img.src = img.dataset.src;
      img.classList.remove('lazy');
    }
  });
  if (lazyloadImages.length == 0) {
    document.removeEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
    window.removeEventListener("resize", lazyload);
    window.removeEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
  }
}, 2);
}

// --- THE IMPORTANT LINE ---
lazyload();

document.addEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
window.addEventListener("resize", lazyload);
window.addEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
}); 
</script>
```

I should point out a couple performance issues with your implementation.

1. it uses `window.innerHeight`, which [can trigger a reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a), a drag on runtime performance (i.e. it causes jankiness)
2. is uses non-passive event listeners, which can also cause jankiness - you can easily [mark them as passive](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/passive-event-listeners)

In general, listening to these events is no longer considered ideal for lazy loading. IntersectionObserver is a more performant alternative. The source for [yall.js](https://github.com/malchata/yall.js?files=1) provides an excellent, easy-to-read example of lazy-loading with IntersectionObserver.